# JQuery Issues on homepage

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, global-messages

I created custom theme. Everything working fine except it doesn't show message on homepage only like add to cart action 
[image]

any other page it's working fine. I think it's KnockoutJS issue. How to tackle that

**default_head_block.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

        <css src="css/style-1.css"/>
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <css src="css/owl.carousel.css"/>
        <css src="css/simple-sidebar.css"/>
        <css src="css/inner.css"/>

        <css src="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js" src_type="url"/>-->
         <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js" src_type="url"/>-->
    <!--<script src="js/new-jquery.js"/>-->
    <!--<script src="js/jquery.js"/>-->
  <!--  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"/>
    <link src="js/custom.js"/>
    <link src="js/html5shiv.js" ie_condition="IE 9" />

    <link src="js/respond.js" ie_condition="IE 9" />
    <link src="js/owl.carousel.js"/>-->    
        <css src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Poppins:400,500" src_type="url"/>
    </head>



</page>
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {

    deps: [
        "js/custom",
    ],

    map: {
        '*': { 

            'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap'

        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"]
    }
};
```

**custom.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function($){
        console.log("jquery log.");
    });
    return;

});
```

**console error **
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Question updated !

Comment: How many jquery library you are using for homepage? As magento already have a jquery and you have added one more?

Comment: @lalitmohan, there are too many JS errors in your console. As per my point of view, you should remove all JS files from layout file and define using require_js.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I removed all js .. updated question with console error